# OCAML merge two sorted list

Tags: sorting, merge, ocaml

I'm trying to write code of merge two lists. We assume that first and second list is sorted with <=. So why I received Exception: Failure "tl".
http://pastebin.com/NXxnfug9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `If` statements you use `l1` and `l2` but I think your intention was to use `li1` and `li2`. Anyway, you should read abut pattern-matching, There, for example: http://www.ffconsultancy.com/ocaml/benefits/pattern_matching.html